# RAM doubled from 8 gb to 16 gb, now ubuntu 13.04 is SO SLOW!

Tags: 13.04, laptop, performance, hp, ram

I upgraded my RAM amount from 8 GB to 16 GB tonight.  After the upgrade Ubuntu takes forever to boot and doing anything on the OS is hideously slow now.  You can click on a menu and it will take minutes to come up.  With 8GB it ran fine, with 16GB it is super slow.  Would anyone know if there is anything you can do to get Ubuntu to run properly again with more RAM?

Comment: Is this matched memory? Have you run a RAM check? What is the CPU / chipset? Did you resize the swap partition? *I'll assume this is 13.04 **64-bit**.*

Comment: Yes, the memory is matched, I ran a RAM check and it is fine.  The CPU is an Intel i5.  The computer is an HP Probook 4540s.  I did not resize the swap partition.  Yes, this is 13.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

Possible known hardware issue:

[Performance issues with ProBook 4540s with 16GB RAM](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/Performance-degrades-in-Probook-4540s-after-memory-upgrade/td-p/2268503)

[Performance degrades in Probook 4540s after memory upgrade](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/Performance-degrades-in-Probook-4540s-after-memory-upgrade/td-p/2268503)

[Processor hangs after adding more RAM to probook 4540s](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Hardware-Upgrades-Replacements/Processor-hangs-after-adding-more-RAM-to-probook-4540s/td-p/2355399)

Although the PDF spec. sheet does suggest support for 16 GB, under 64-bit Windows or Linux.

[ProBook 4540s Notebook PC (datasheet)](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/pscmisc/vac/us/product_pdfs/HP_ProBook_4540s_datasheet.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

- Check your load and your psu.
- Check your ram slot - some motherboard need in parallel or series to optimize the performance.
- Greater ram means greater load. Check how many your m/b can support.
- Check your ram speed if its compatible with the m/b.
- How about performance under windows?

I am sure this is just an hardware issue. You may want to open your m/b manual again. This issue always come in some laptop where it says it can support, but at the same time slow down the performance.